# How to edit SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing Android application, and I have one question - ListView uses SimpleCursorAdapter (this cursor gets information from SQLite db), but if I edit my database then ListView will be empty. How can I fix it? I want that after editing ListView will refresh. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Adapter:

```
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
            DictionaryDbWrapper.getInstance().getAllWords(), new String[]{DictionaryDbHelper.WORD, DictionaryDbHelper.CATEGORY},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Updating code:

```
    mDb.update(DictionaryDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, word, DictionaryDbHelper._ID+"=?", 
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you need to assign Adapter to ListView after each refresh?

Comment: I don't want to do it because Cursor contains a lot of items.

Comment: i am afraid this is the only way

Answer (score 0):

After you modify your database, create a new cursor and call `adapter.changeCursor(newCursor)`.

Comment: If my Cursor contains a lot of elements it will refresh long or not?

Comment: It will not matter to the adapter, since it will only iterate over what is viewable.